# Action bar theme takes over the whole activity

Tags: android

I am new android and i was playing with recycler views.

I tried building a music application with its songs listed inside a recycler  view.

[image]

This is the final output. I can play songs by clicking on the list but i can't understand why there is a black foreground in front.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.tilak.imusicplay">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/android_music_player_play"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Activity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF330000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_parent_view">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: check in your code if there is some code running in service and inflating a layout which is producing black foreground color

Comment: <service android:name="com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService" />
this one mainly

Comment: no, it's not @vikaskumar